# problema con sesion en php

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo un problema con el inicio de sesión de un sistema que estoy tratando de realizar ... Resulta que la variable de sesión queda abierta y es imposible cerrarla; no entiendo que pasa, estoy usando session_start y session_destroy; No se si sea un problema de caché porque cuando refresco la pagina si hace el login pero luego no deja cerrarlo. Además, cuando hago el logín con un usuario, me muesta la información de éste y cuando refresco, me muestra la información del usuario con login anterior. Adjunto un código sencillo. DE ANTEMANO MUCHAS GRACIAS POR SUS APORTES.

index.php:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    
    session_start();
    
    if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    ?>
    
        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
            <label for="user">Usuario:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pwd">
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Registro">
        </form>
    <?php
    }else{
        $codprof = $_SESSION['userid'];
        echo "Hola ".$codprof."<br />";
        echo "<a href='logout.php'>Cerrar Sesión</a>";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

include_once "conexion.php";
$con = conexion();

$con_prof = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM docente WHERE usuario = '$user' AND pwd = '$pwd'");
$usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($con_prof);

session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = $usuario[0];

header("location: index.php");
```

logout.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();

header("location: index.php");

?>
```

De nuevo agradezco la ayuda que me pueden brindar ... Soy novato en esto y ya no sé que hacer ...

Comment: //session_id(session_id());
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_commit();

Comment: _[`session_start`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) debe ser llamada antes de imprimir cualquier cosa en el navegador._, con esto quiero señalar que tu archivo `index.php` debería estar dando error.

Comment: Gracias por responder... Marcos, ya lo puse al inicio pero el problema persiste... Funciona con los dos primeros usuarios registrados y luego queda mostrando un usuario anterior..

Comment: El problema que tengo no es de php, ya lo probé y funciona... al parecer el problema viene siendo del lado del cliente, porque cuando refresco, muestra la información que solicito

Comment: Pon un `session_unset();` antes de `session_destroy();` en logout.php. Y si aún no funciona, échale un ojo en [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-unset.php), a la primera contribución de los usuarios más abajo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios... Ya lo pude solucionar... Arreglé lo que me comentaron y además de eso utilicé:   <script type="text/javascript">
            function clearjQueryCache(){ 
                for (var x in jQuery.cache){ 
                    delete jQuery.cache[x]; 
                } 
            } 
        </script>